# A zero byte allocation should be considered a leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I'm checking memory allocation with poolmon for a C application, after uninstall it still have 1 allocation with zero bytes. Can this be considered as a memory leak?

Comment: Yes, since `malloc(0)` is not required to return `NULL`.

Comment: did you check the heap before you did any allocations?

Answer (score 1):

It's an implementation defined.

But even malloc(0) must be free()'d.

Comment: "malloc(0) must be free()'d" if the result is not `NULL`.